# "xlsx" file created from php gives format error when opening in excel

Tags: php, excel

Initially I created downloadable "xls" file from php and it is opening in Excel. But when I create xlsx file, it is stored with the correct file name and extension but it gives error "Excel cannot open the file 'myfile.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted"

Header info settings code of my PHP is:

```
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"filename.xlsx\"");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
```

And the code that enters values in excel file is:

```
 // Define separator (defines columns in excel; tabs in word)
 $sep = "\t"; // tabbed character

// Start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i<mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
 echo mysql_field_name($result, $i) . "\t";
}
print("\n");
// End of printing column names

// Start while loop to get data
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{

$schema_insert = "";
for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result); $j++)
{
if(!isset($row[$j])) {
  $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
}
elseif ($row[$j] != "") {
  $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
}
else {
  $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
}
 }
 $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
 $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
 $schema_insert .= "\t";
 print(trim($schema_insert));
 print "\n";
  }
```

What could be the problem in it?

Comment: So how are you actually creating your file? You don't simply set headings, you have to create the content somehow. What library are you using?

Comment: I am not using any library. Just simply echoing and I know that the code is working fine as "xls" file is created from the same code. Still I have edited my question and have pasted that part of the code as well.

Comment: Thats not a valid xls file. Go open a real xls file in notepad and compare

Comment: I have already mentioned that xls file is valid and it can be downloaded and it is working. I want "xlsx" file

Comment: And I opened the created "xls" file and the "xlsx" file in notepad, both the results are same and clear. No problem in that

Comment: If you're just echoing CSV text, then you're not creating a real Excel file, just a file containing that html which has a `.xls` or an `.xlsx` extension.... a real Excel file is a binary, you can't read a real Excel file in notepad.... MS Excel may read it, but it knows that it isn't a real Excel file, and the most recent versions of MS Excel lets you know that you're trying to confuse it

Comment: And if you really have to create a csv file, then use PHP's built-in fputcsv() function rather than writing your own (and your code won't even create a valid csv in many cases)

Comment: If you want to create a real BIFF-format `.xls` or OfficeOpenXML-format `.xlsx` file, then I'd recommend using a library like [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) that can write these formats